# Motor stalls and starts smoking after roughly 5 seconds

Tags: motor, clone-brands, power-functions

I have done everything that I was supposed to (with the setup), and when I press the button to supply power to the motor, it stalls (sometimes), and when it *does* spin, I can see a small puff of white smoke coming out from the front.

I use the Lego Power Functions motor with non-LEGO battery box that has 4 outputs. Before today, everything worked fine.

Comment: Hi Stanley and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you please add more details about the pieces being used? Or photos, if that's easier for you. It would be mainly interesting to see whether the pieces are genuine LEGO parts, whether they show any signs of damage and if they are connected in a way that does let them work as intended. Of course you could and should try to swap them out for other similar parts, if you have additional motors, cables or battery boxes around.

Comment: Hi Stanley, you say you use a battery box that has 4 outputs. However there is no such battery box in the Power Functions line of products. There is however such a battery box in the Powered Up line of products. Could you please clarify? If you are actually using Powered Up, your best bet is to contact Lego Customer Service, as Powered Up components are relatively recent products, they'll happily replace any defective parts...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve https://www.amazon.com/PHYNEDI-Modification-Accessories-Building-Extension/dp/B094VHHXJP/ref=sr_1_2?crid=DNZBCI9CPLN6&keywords=lego%2Bmotor%2Bphynedi&qid=1668634345&sprefix=lego%2Bmotor%2B%2Caps%2C347&sr=8-2&th=1 (yes I know it's off brand)

Comment: I took a liberty to clarify you question with vital information about battery box being not a genuine LEGO piece. Based on this information I suspect battery box to be a culprit of your issue. I would advise you to stop using this battery box with any LEGO motors if you want to keep your other motors intact.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try to buy an actual PF battery box. If this works, and you make an answer, I'll gladly accept!